# Facebook auth setup

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, paw-app

How can I setup PAW to work with Facebook locally for development? Or even at all for that matter?

I have a node.js backend that I'm setting up with Facebook Auth. Every one of my routes needs the user to be logged in. I have two endpoints related to FB Auth. localhost:3000/api/v1/loginFB and localhost:3000/api/v1/callbackFB. Both of these work great in a web browser.

loginFB simply returns this string... https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=523534457345&redirect_uri=https://localhost:3000/api/v1/callbackFB&scope=email,public_profile,user_friends.

When I call that URI in a browser, it returns a code=blahblah which my callbackFB endpoint uses to fire off another request to get the access token. All good.

So now in PAW I'm confused by the difference between the request URI and the Authorization URL text field? Should I use the loginFB URI for my request URI? And then https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth in the Authorization URL textfield?

Basically what's happening is that when I click Get Access Token, it returns the code but my callbackFB endpoint 500's by saying "This authorization code has been used." The code that it's getting returned is definitely different each time I Get Access Token.

This is where I'm at with this thing (Client ID and Client Secret are actually my App ID and App Secret from fb's dev management site, and the Access Token URL is actually set to https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/oauth/access_token which I'm 99% sure is the correct URI):
[image: OAuth2 window]

This is the error I get when I click Get Access Token button:
[image: Get access token error]

It would be awesome to get some advice from anyone with experience with this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Similar problem, except mine just hangs with a "Waiting for Authorization..." message

Comment: @MasonBryant Is your setup functional with a simple web page? Or any other method for that matter? I've emailed the PAW guys but haven't received a reply yet. I emailed them the same day I posted this thread fwiw.

Comment: Sorry for the super late follow-up. We actually fix this exact issue in Paw 2.2.2, which is already released on our website, and pending review for the Mac App Store. (It was some JSON vs. Form URL-Encoded parsing issue). Thanks for reporting.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @MichaMazaheri! Any idea of when that update will hit the app store?

Comment: @MasonBryant my hung too until i added https:// to the urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re: @MichaMazaheri

tl;dr Fixed in version 2.2.2

Sorry for the super late follow-up. We actually fix this exact issue in Paw 2.2.2, which is already released on our website, and pending review for the Mac App Store. (It was some JSON vs. Form URL-Encoded parsing issue). Thanks for reporting.